# Two DataTables in one page - how to scroll just one of the tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, datatable

I have two DataTables in one page initialized as follows:

```
      //First table
    sListTable = $('#subListTable').dataTable({
                "sScrollY": "265px",
                "sDom": "frtiS",
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {"sType": "date", "aTargets": [1]}
                ]
    });

      //Second table
    pListTable = $('#projListTable').dataTable({
                "sScrollY": "265px",
                "sDom": "frtiS",
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {"sType": "date", "aTargets": [1]}
                ]
    });
```

As you can see, I'm using a separate variable for each table and each table has it's own unique ID.

Now I have a function that automatically highlights a row in the "projListTable" table and scrolls that row into view based on some event:

```
//Auto-scroll to row with 'row_selected' class                          
var container = $('#projListTable,div.dataTables_scrollBody');
var scrollTo = $('#projListTable tbody tr.row_selected');
container.scrollTop(scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top);
```

This auto-scrolling script is working fine, BUT the problem is that it also scrolls the other table (sListTable) even though "projListTable" is specifically specified as shown above.

What do I need to do, such that only "projListTable" is the only one affected by the the container.scrollTop() call?  I have a feeling it's because they share "div.dataTables_scrollBody", but I can't figure out how to get around with it. Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the code in action showing the problem:

http://live.datatables.net/ekatik/8

Comment: var container = $('#projListTable');  right?

Comment: Nope. Auto-scrolling totally stopped working when I changed it to that.

Comment: Added an example link showing the problem.  http://live.datatables.net/ekatik/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just select the targetted table `.dataTables_scrollBody`, using this:

[SEE DEMO](http://live.datatables.net/ekatik/9)

```
  var container = $('#projListTable').closest('.dataTables_scrollBody');
  var scrollTo = $('#projListTable tbody tr.row_selected');
  container.scrollTop(0); 
  container.scrollTop(scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top);
```